# Catch the Error message text in a rxjs subscribe method in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, rxjs

I have a nodeJS express server application in TypeScript. When an error occurs I want to add some text to it and read it in the client Angular application.

**NodeJS Server, express  code:**

```
import {
  Request,
  Response
} from 'express';

if (medewerker) {
  verifyPassword(medewerker.id, req.body.wachtwoord).then(isVerifiedPassword => {

    if (isVerifiedPassword) {

      .......

    } else {
      throw new Error('Wachtwoord niet juist ingevoerd');
    }

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(401).json('I want to show this text: ' + error);
  })
}
```

**Client code:**

```
this.httpClient.put(this.url + 'medewerker/login', {
    'email': authData.userId,
    'wachtwoord': authData.password
  }, {
    headers: this.headertjes,
    withCredentials: true,
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'json'
  })
  .subscribe((data1: HttpResponse < MedewerkerTypeId > ) => {

    if (data1 != null) {
      .....
    }

  }, ((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(error.statusText) //here I want to grep and show my text.
  }));
```

But I get an error: undefined message. 
I tried all the options but only default properties like  `error.status` and `error.message` works. But no Custom messages like I want.

Maybe somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the `ErrorResponse` can be accessed  using the `error` property.

Change your code like this:

```
this.httpClient.put(this.url + 'medewerker/login', {
    'email': authData.userId,
    'wachtwoord': authData.password
  }, {
    headers: this.headertjes,
    withCredentials: true,
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'json'
  })
  .subscribe((data1: HttpResponse < MedewerkerTypeId > ) => {

    if (data1 != null) {
      .....
    }

  }, ((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(error.error) //here error contains the text
  }));
```